# Solve $f(x)=\int_{-1}^{1} f(t) \text{d}t$

Tags: calculus

How can I solve $f(x)=\int_{-1}^{1} f(t) \text{d}t$? Clearly $f(x)=0$ is a solution, but is there any other?

Comment: Note the right hand side is a constant.

Comment: Nitpick: the letter $x$ is being used as an independent variable on the left-hand side but as a bound variable on the right-hand side; it'd be better to write something like $$f(x) = \int_{-1}^1 f(t)\, dt$$ so that there's no confusion. This would also make the solution easier to see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{d g(x)}{dx}$

$\displaystyle\implies \frac{d g(x)}{dx}=\int_{-1}^1\frac{d g(x)}{dx}dx=g(1)-g(-1) $

$\displaystyle\implies d g(x)=[g(1)-g(-1)] dx$

Integrating either sides $\displaystyle g(x)=[g(1)-g(-1)]x+K$

$\displaystyle\implies f(x)=\frac{d g(x)}{dx}=[g(1)-g(-1)]$

Now put the value of $f(x)$ in the given relation

Comment: So the only solutions are constants? Such a shame, I was expecting some periodic solution :(

Comment: Ah! I found my mistake, let me open another question.

Comment: What I really meant to ask is this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658615/solve-fx-int-x-1x1-ft-textdt
Sorry for my confusion.