# Solve $f(x)=\int_{x-1}^{x+1} f(t) \text{d}t$

Tags: calculus, integration

Solve $f(x)=\int_{x-1}^{x+1} f(t) \text{d}t$. We know that $f(x)=0$ is a solution, are there any other solutions?

I suppose I can start with $f(x)=\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$, and then:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{dg(x)}{dx}&=\int_{x-1}^{x+1} \frac{dg(t)}{dt} dt \\
\frac{dg(x)}{dx}&=g(x+1)-g(x-1) \\
\end{align*}$$

But then I'm stuck.

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem?  So-called 'delay-differential' equations are notoriously difficult and tend not to have clean analytical solutions.

Comment: Also, you have 'past' and 'future' values in the ODE which complicates matters even more...

Comment: I was trying to model a random walk where a frog lies on a one-dimensional rope and jumps to a uniform random position in the [x-1,x+1] neighborhood on each iteration.

Comment: If you're trying to model the random walk, you should have a normalizing factor of $\frac12$ in front of the integral, which makes the problem rather different as now all linear functions are solutions.

Comment: @Ricbit I have edited my post significantly. It actually now includes the solution given in the Math Overflow post you made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better yet you can differentiate both sides since $f$ will be smooth (convince yourself of this). Then what you have is (by FToC)

$$f'(x) = f(x+1)-f(x-1)$$

We want to solve this equation. **As per user Doubt**, note that $f(x)=a$ is a solution to the ODE but not to the integral equation (unless $a=0$).

I will then assume that $f$ is nonconstant and is a true function. Further, let's assume the function has a Fourier transform. If we take the Fourier transform, where

$$\mathcal{F}f(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ikx}f(x)dx,$$

we get that

$$ik\mathcal{F}f(k)=e^{ik}\mathcal{F}f(k)-e^{-ik}\mathcal{F}f(k).$$

This has to hold true for all $k$. So we can rewrite this as

$$(ik-2i\sin(k))\mathcal{F}f(k) = 0.$$

Since $k=2\sin k$ only for $k=0,\pm1.89549$, we see that $\mathcal{F}f(k) = 0$ almost everywhere and so $f(x) = 0$ almost everywhere.

---

Let us suppose then that $f$ is distributional in nature, particularly a tempered distribution. We can make sense of distributional derivatives so the above differential still holds but some of the later steps will be different.

Since $f$ is a tempered distribution, it has a Fourier transform. Let $\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. a Schwartz function, then

$$\begin{eqnarray}\langle f',\phi\rangle &=& \langle f_1-f_{-1},\phi\rangle\\
&=&\langle f_1,\phi\rangle-\langle f_{-1},\phi\rangle\\
&=&\langle f,\phi_{-1}\rangle-\langle f,\phi_1\rangle\end{eqnarray}$$

where $f_a(x) = f(a+x)$. We also have that $\langle f',\phi\rangle = -\langle f,\phi'\rangle$ so that

$$-\langle f,\phi'\rangle = \langle f,\phi_{-1}-\phi_1\rangle.$$

Equivalently, $\langle f,\phi'-\phi_1+\phi_{-1}\rangle = 0$. Taking a Fourier transform, we see that

$$\langle \mathcal{F}^{-1}f,\mathcal{F}(\phi'-\phi_1+\phi_{-1})\rangle = 0.$$

Then we see that

$$\langle \mathcal{F}^{-1}f,-ik\mathcal{F}\phi-e^{-ik}\mathcal{F}\phi+e^{ik}\mathcal{F}\phi\rangle_k = 0,$$

where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_k$ indicates that the distributional integral is over $k$. Then by linearity,

$$\langle (-ik-e^{-ik}+e^{ik})\mathcal{F}^{-1}f,\mathcal{F}\phi\rangle_k = 0.$$

Since the Fourier transform is an automorphism of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, $\mathcal{F}\phi$ is just another Schwartz function. Thus

$$\langle (-ik+2i\sin k)\mathcal{F}^{-1}f,\psi\rangle_k = 0,$$

where $\psi$ is an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Thus we see that $(2\sin k-k)\mathcal{F}^{-1}f(k) = 0$, in a distributional sense, just like above. To be extremely handwavy about it: If $2\sin k -k\neq 0$, then the (inverse) Fourier transform of $f$ must be zero. However, if $2\sin k = k$, then the (inverse) Fourier transform of $f$ can take on any value. This is exactly why we have the solution that was noted on your Math Overflow post. If you were to take the Fourier transform of the solution given by Noam, you would see that it is a Dirac delta centered at the point $k=2\sin k$.

Comment: "and so $f(x) = 0$ almost everywhere": and so, from the original equation, $f(x) = 0$ everywhere.

Comment: Actually your argument works in Schwartz class $\mathscr S'(\mathscr R)$, where $$\langle f,\varphi\rangle=\langle {\mathcal F}f,{\mathcal F}^{-1}\varphi\rangle=0,$$ for all $\varphi\in{\mathscr S}(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: What about f(x)=DiracDelta(cos(2 pi x)) - DiracDelta(sin(2 pi x))? I think it is a solution as well.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Thanks for the clarification. That was exactly my intention (I just wanted to avoid using the distributional argument since it's almost the same).

Comment: @Ricbit How exactly would you integrate a Dirac delta composed with sine and cosine? It's not immediately clear to me.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, for every positive real eps, the integral from n-eps to n+eps of DiracDelta[Sin[2 Pi x]] is 1 for every integral n, and 0 everywhere.

Comment: @Ricbit I tried working it out and got something different. Formally manipulating the integral, we have

$$\int_{x-1}^{x+1}\delta(\sin(2\pi t))dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\sin(2\pi(x-1))}^{\sin(2\pi(x+1))}\delta(u)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du,$$

where I've let $u=\sin(2\pi t)$. I think you get $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ from this.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I wonder if there's a way to fix this dirac solution to make it work, or if the constant 0 is indeed the only solution.

Comment: @Ricbit I'm not sure. I did the formal manipulation of the Dirac deltas and found that $f(x+1)-f(x-1) = 0$. I think the zero solution is the only solution unfortunately but maybe you could post this in Math Overflow. There are, undoubtedly, better people with better knowledge of distribution theory than me who might be able to help you.

Comment: I wasn't aware of Math Overflow, thanks for your solution and for the redirect!

Comment: Note that $f(x) = a \in\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f^\prime(x) = f(x+1) - f(x-1)$, but not the original problem $f(x) = \int^{x+1}_{x-1}f(t)\,dt$.

Comment: @Doubt Good point!

Comment: @Doubt I implicitly assumed $f$ was not constant it seems, but your indication fixes that for me. I'll edit my post (for posterity).

Answer (score 8):

A set of solutions is $$f(x) = a\sin(\omega x) + b\cos(\omega x)$$ for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.  Note that $$\int_{x-1}^{x+1}f(t)\,dt = \frac{2\sin\omega}{\omega}\left(a\sin(\omega x)+b\cos(\omega x)\right)= \frac{2\sin\omega}{\omega}f(x)$$
so $\omega$ must be chosen to satisfy $$\frac{2\sin\omega}{\omega} = 1.$$  Numerically, $\omega \approx \pm 1.89549$.

Comment: This is similar to a solution proposed by Yiorgos below.

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to find this solution without guessing its form?

Answer (score 2):

An attempt for a solution is to try
$$
f(x)=\mathrm{e}^{ax}, 
$$
and this implies that
$a$ satisfies equation $\mathrm{e}^a-\mathrm{e}^{-a}=a$. Unfortunately, the only solution of this equation is $a=0$, and the corresponding exponential function is not a solution of our equation.

Clearly, we need to assume some smoothness for $f$. Let's assume that $f$ is continuous. Then, the right hand side is continuously differentiable, and thus we can differentiate, and obtain, as you have already done the equation
$$
f'(x)=f(x+1)-f(x-1), \quad \text{for all}\,\, x.
$$

Comment: ${x \over 2} = \sinh x$ only has $0$ as a solution (over the reals, at least).

Comment: You actually don't need to assume smoothness as long as you assume $f$ is measurable (otherwise why would you be integrating it?) because $f$ is then the integral of a measurable function, which is always continuous. Repeat inductively to see that $f$ is smooth.

Comment: Still, it a reasonable first shot to assume smoothness and then validate afterwards...

Comment: @copper.hat: Undoubtedly!

Comment: $f(x) = e^{0x} = 1$ is not a solution even though $a=0$ fulfills the condition $e^a-e^{-a}=a$.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala: Correct.

Answer (score 1):

(Written up as a solution since it's a bit too long for a comment: )

Another approach that doesn't work: suppose $g$ is a polynomial of degree $d$.  Then $\frac{dg}{dx}$ will be a polynomial of degree $d-1$, and so will $g(x+1)-g(x-1)$ (the leading term cancels).  Since the equation is linear, we can assume $g$ a monic polynomial (i.e., with a leading term of $x^d$).  But then the leading term of $\frac{dg}{dx}$ will be $dx^{d-1}$, whereas the leading term of $g(x+1)-g(x-1)$ will be $2dx^{d-1}$.

In fact, you should be able to extend this approach to show that the only analytic solution is the constant function, since $g'(x)$ is 'twice as large' as would be expected from a naive central-difference approximation everywhere.